# linux parallel execution and get status error

Tags: linux, shell, parallel-processing

The parallel execution is working properly as expected. But i need to get the states of each file. Here I need to check it by using the if condition. This is just a sample and i have many scenarios like this in my code.

I'm a beginner at #help shell scripts & linux but actually i love linux now.
I'm expecting an alternative method or a help to resolve this. Thank you everyone.

```
( echo $FILE_PATH/import_csv_location_data_into_hive.sh; echo $FILE_PATH/import_csv_order_data_into_hive.sh; echo $FILE_PATH/import_csv_order_with_delivery_info_into_hive.sh; ) | parallel bash 

wait
IMPORTED_LOCATIONS_STATUS=$? IMPORTED_ORDERS_STATUS=$? IMPORTED_ORDERS_WITH_DELIVERY_INFO_STATUS=$?


if [[ "$IMPORTED_LOCATIONS_STATUS" == "0" && "$IMPORTED_ORDERS_STATUS" == "0" && "$IMPORTED_ORDERS_WITH_DELIVERY_INFO_STATUS" == "0" ]];
then
  echo  "COMPLETED."
  exit 0 
else
  STATUS="FAILED."
  exit 1
fi
```

Sample code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZsVC.png)

Comment: Please click [edit] then select your code with your mouse. Then click `{}` in the Formatting Toolbar beside **Bold** and *Italic* to format as code. Thank you.

Comment: @lc wanigasinghe – Why do you say "i need to get the states of each file" when you only cumulate the statuses to a single `COMPLETED` or `FAILED`?

Comment: @JamesRisner hi, thank you your comment. In here i need to run all files parallely and need to get the Complete or Failed status at the end.

Comment: @toyotaSupra thank you for your comment. actually i need to run three or more files parallely and get the complete or filed status at the end. because i have another dependency on the results of these files.

Answer (score 1):

```
(echo Your-Special-Header; \
    echo whoami; \
    echo cat nothere \
) | parallel --header : --results all.csv bash -c
```

The file nothere does not exist. Here is the csv output:

```
Seq,Host,Starttime,JobRuntime,Send,Receive,Exitval,Signal,Command,Your-Special-Header,Stdout,Stderr
1,:,1662823208.481,0.001,0,5,0,0,"bash -c whoami",whoami,"root
",
2,:,1662823208.481,0.003,0,0,1,0,"bash -c cat\ nothere","cat nothere",,"cat: nothere: No such file or directory
"
```

The 7th column is Exitval.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to know if *all* finished with no errors:

```
(
 echo $FILE_PATH/import_csv_location_data_into_hive.sh;
 echo $FILE_PATH/import_csv_order_data_into_hive.sh;
 echo $FILE_PATH/import_csv_order_with_delivery_info_into_hive.sh;
) | parallel bash

if [[ "$?" == "0" ]]; then
  echo  "COMPLETED."
  exit 0 
else
  STATUS="FAILED."
  exit 1
fi
```

Shorter, but less readable IMO:

```
(
 echo $FILE_PATH/import_csv_location_data_into_hive.sh;
 echo $FILE_PATH/import_csv_order_data_into_hive.sh;
 echo $FILE_PATH/import_csv_order_with_delivery_info_into_hive.sh;
) | if parallel bash ; then
  echo  "COMPLETED."
  exit 0 
else
  STATUS="FAILED."
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. yes its very helpful but i need to get the execution status one by one. ( 0 or 1 status of the each file )

Comment: @lcwanigasinghe ... in that case James' solution is better. In case you will need to re-run the failed jobs, look at --retry-failed and --resume-failed.